# Foreign key and Association in gorm not created correctly

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I tried to make models Association ForeignKey on PostgreSQL for the Person it belongs to Data and Data belongs to Person 
this is my struct

```
type (
    Data struct {
        ID          uint `gorm:"auto_increment"`
        PersonID    uint
        Person      *Person `gorm:"foreignkey:id;association_foreignkey:PersonID"`
        Birthday    *time.Time
        Salary      float64 `gorm:"type:money"`
    }

    Person struct {
        gorm.Model
        Email    string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index;not null"`
        Password string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
        Role     string `gorm:"type:varchar(30);not null"`
        DataID   uint
        Data     *Data `gorm:"foreignkey:id;association_foreignkey:DataID"`
    }
)
```

I want to on Data table has `Person_id` is to be foreign key from Person table, and as well the Person table has `Data_id` to be foreign key from the data table after I see on ER Diagram on my DBeaver, those are not created as I wish :( it is not any relationship on ER Diagram, I am sure my Association  on above wrong, can anyone give me some info to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gorm's functions for that when you automigrate your database.

```
db.Model(&Data{}).AddForeignKey("person", "person(id)", "NO ACTION", "NO ACTION")
db.Model(&Person{}).AddForeignKey("data", "data(id)", "NO ACTION", "NO ACTION")
```

You can check this aswell: [Gorm Migration](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html)